# How to work with DTO in Spring Data REST projects?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, projection, dto

Spring Data REST automates exposing only domain object. But most often we have to deal with Data Transfer Objects. So how to do this in SDR way?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**An approach of how to work with [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) in [Spring Data REST](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) projects**

*The working example is [here](https://github.com/Cepr0/spring-data-rest-dto)*

**Entities**

Entities must implement the [Identifiable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/hateoas/Identifiable.html) interface. For example:

```java
@Entity
public class Category implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final Integer id;

    private final String name;

    @OneToMany
    private final Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();

    // skipped
}

@Entity
public class Product implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final Integer id;

    private final String name;

    // skipped
}
```

**Projections**

Make a [projection](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods) interface that repository query methods will return:

```java
public interface CategoryProjection {

    Category getCategory();
    Long getQuantity();
}
```

It will be a basement for DTO. In this example DTO will represent a `Category` and the number of `Product`s are belong to it.

**Repository methods**

Create methods return the projection: a single one, a list of DTO and a paged list of DTO.

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CategoryRepo extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Query("select c as category, count(p) as quantity from Category c join c.products p where c.id = ?1 group by c")
    CategoryProjection getDto(Integer categoryId);

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Query("select c as category, count(p) as quantity from Category c join c.products p group by c")
    List<CategoryProjection> getDtos();

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Query("select c as category, count(p) as quantity from Category c join c.products p group by c")
    Page<CategoryProjection> getDtos(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**DTO**

Implement DTO from its interface:

```java
@Relation(value = "category", collectionRelation = "categories")
public class CategoryDto implements CategoryProjection {

    private final Category category;
    private final Long quantity;

    // skipped
}
```

Annotation `Relation` is used when Spring Data REST is rendering the object.

**Controller**

Add custom methods to `RepositoryRestController` that will serve requests of DTO:

```java
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired private CategoryRepo repo;
    @Autowired private RepositoryEntityLinks links;
    @Autowired private PagedResourcesAssembler<CategoryProjection> assembler;

    /**
    * Single DTO
    */
    @GetMapping("/{id}/dto")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getDto(@PathVariable("id") Integer categoryId) {
        CategoryProjection dto = repo.getDto(categoryId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(toResource(dto));
    }

    /**
    * List of DTO
    */
    @GetMapping("/dto")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getDtos() {
        List<CategoryProjection> dtos = repo.getDtos();

        Link listSelfLink = links.linkFor(Category.class).slash("/dto").withSelfRel();
        List<?> resources = dtos.stream().map(this::toResource).collect(toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Resources<>(resources, listSelfLink));
    }

    /**
    * Paged list of DTO
    */
    @GetMapping("/dtoPaged")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getDtosPaged(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<CategoryProjection> dtos = repo.getDtos(pageable);

        Link pageSelfLink = links.linkFor(Category.class).slash("/dtoPaged").withSelfRel();
        PagedResources<?> resources = assembler.toResource(dtos, this::toResource, pageSelfLink);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
    }

    private ResourceSupport toResource(CategoryProjection projection) {
        CategoryDto dto = new CategoryDto(projection.getCategory(), projection.getQuantity());

        Link categoryLink = links.linkForSingleResource(projection.getCategory()).withRel("category");
        Link selfLink = links.linkForSingleResource(projection.getCategory()).slash("/dto").withSelfRel();

        return new Resource<>(dto, categoryLink, selfLink);
    }
}
```

When Projections are received from repository we must make the final transformation from a Projection to DTO 
and 'wrap' it to [ResourceSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceSupport.html) object before sending to the client. 
To do this we use helper method `toResource`: we create a new DTO, create necessary links for this object, 
and then create a new `Resource` with the object and its links.

**Result**

*See the API docs on the [Postman site](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/788154/spring-data-rest-dto/6mz3FWE)*

**Singe DTO**

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/categories/6/dto
```

```json
{
    "category": {
        "name": "category1"
    },
    "quantity": 3,
    "_links": {
        "category": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/6"
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/6/dto"
        }
    }
}
```

**List of DTO**

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/categories/dto
```

```json
{
    "_embedded": {
        "categories": [
            {
                "category": {
                    "name": "category1"
                },
                "quantity": 3,
                "_links": {
                    "category": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/6"
                    },
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/6/dto"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "name": "category2"
                },
                "quantity": 2,
                "_links": {
                    "category": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/7"
                    },
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/7/dto"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/dto"
        }
    }
}
```

**Paged list of DTO**

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/categories/dtoPaged
```

```json
{
    "_embedded": {
        "categories": [
            {
                "category": {
                    "name": "category1"
                },
                "quantity": 3,
                "_links": {
                    "category": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/6"
                    },
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/6/dto"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "name": "category2"
                },
                "quantity": 2,
                "_links": {
                    "category": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/7"
                    },
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/7/dto"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/categories/dtoPaged"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 2,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you use final fields in `CategoryDto`? It's not compilable.

Comment: and what code is //skipped ? do you skip getters and setters? I can't compile your example

Comment: а есть ли какой-то способ программно к проекции добавить линки на другие сущности? у меня в коде динамически определяется в какой проекции отправлять page с сущностями, происходит трансформация, но я не могу добавить _links на другие объекты внутри элементов страницы

Comment: @CatH Используй [ResourceProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_resourceprocessor_interface) и [RepositoryEntityLinks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_programmatic_links). [Пример](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/ResourceProcessors.java)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157978/discussion-between-cat-h-and-cepr0).

Comment: Where is the source that states Entities must implement Identifiable?

Comment: When using Spring Data Rest, by default it creates an endpoint that returns my entity with links to itself and its related entities. Isn't there a way to use this capability in a custom controller to avoid manual converting the entity to a Resource?

Comment: This is a pretty nice example. Thank you for it. However, I was wondering what is the benefit of using Spring-Data-Rest if we disable all methods in the repository, i.e. "exported = false". And we also set the HATEOAS links manually in the controller. What do we get from SDR?

Comment: @egelev We don't disable 'all' repo methods, only our custom ones.

Comment: To convert incoming DTO classes to entities, this approach seems fine: https://auth0.com/blog/automatically-mapping-dto-to-entity-on-spring-boot-apis/ It is using custom annotation, ModelMapper and `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.