# By default, don't expose field in Entity class, using Spring Data Rest and Jpa

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data-rest

I have an entity class Account. It has a bunch of fields. Most of them for now are exposed in REST calls except where I explicitly ignore the password field with `@JsonIgnore`, but I will be adding more fields and I don't want to forget adding @JsonIgnore to something new that shouldn't be exposed.

Can I invert the exposure, so that I explicitly have to enable fields to be exported, with the default being that it won't be exposed?

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Data
@ToString(exclude = "password")
@Entity
public class Account {

    public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore private String password;

    private String[] roles;

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(password);
    }

    protected Account() {}

    public Account(String name, String password, String... roles) {

        this.name = name;
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

Using Spring Data REST here, so everything else that is there is just repositories, there is no extra layer to do something smart.

Answer (score 2):

There is two main ways to get the "white-list" properties effect in `Jackson` library

**First Way:**

Remove `@Data` annotation from your `Account` class and add getters only to fields you want to expose. To make sure that properties without getters will not be excludes add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` to your `Account` class

**Second Way:**

Wrap your `Account` class with `AccountForJson` class. for example :

```
public class AccountForJson {

private Account account;

public MyClassForJson(Account accountToWrapped) {
    this.account = accountToWrapped;
}

/**
 * Example of property that you want to expose
 */
public String getName() {
    return this.account.getName();
 }
}
```

p.s : there is an open issuse in `Jackson` github repository for that feature, here is the link for watching that issuse - [Add `@JsonIncludeProperties(propertyNames)` (reverse of `@JsonIgnoreProperties`)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1296)

Comment: Thanks! I could go with the 2nd option, the first is hard because I do want to access some fields from classes within my application, while not exposing them through rest. It seems a bit of a workaround though, was hoping for an option within Jackson or Spring.

Comment: Third way: create a dedicate data class (Dto) to expose only the fields you want :)

Comment: @Dherik could you elaborate in an answer a bit? That seems a bit hard to do in a Spring Data REST application that automatically exposes Repository classes providing the entities through REST.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek with Spring Data Rest is [not so easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45401735/2387977), you are right. My "third way" would not use Spring Data Rest: you create some "Dto"s for the endpoints and populate them with the entity informations with some mapper lib, exposing only the fields you want. It's a extra layer, for sure. Spring Data Rest is not so flexible and, for me, incentives a bad practice.

Comment: @Dherik yeah I’m really considering just dropping Spring Data Rest altogether. What bad practices would you say it incentives?

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek, 1. expose the entity in your "view" layer (this alone brings a lot of problems: reduces your flexibility, some changes in entity will change your REST contract, difficult to have different representations for the same entity, etc); 2. mix your entity with Json annotations, Validation annotations, JPA annotations, etc (this is a nightmare for maintenance, IMHO), 3. violates the SRP (your entity have a lot of responsibilities).