# How to depict joins with @Query annotation in Spring JPA Repository method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring-Boot with JPA and a MySQL backend. Now I got quite confused about the repositories Spring-Boot provides. I know these are quite powerful (and seem to be quite useful since they can shorten your code a lot). Still, I do not understand how to represent Joins within them, since the result-set should be a combination of specified attributes in the select of a few Entities.

Now let's assume we have three tables `Book`, `Author`, `AuthorOfBook`, where the last one is simply connecting `Book` and `Author` by a combined Primary key. I guess we had the following Java-Classes:

**Entity Book:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOK")
public class Book {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "TITLE")
  private String title;

}
```

**Entity Author**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AUTHOR")
public class Author {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
  private String lastname;
  @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
  private String firstname;
  //Let's assume some getters and setters and a constructor
}
```

**Entity AuthorOfBook:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOK")
public class Book {
  @EmbeddedId
  private AuthorOfBookId pk;
}
```

**An Embedded ID**

```
@Embeddable
public class AuthorOfBookId implements Serializable {
  private int authorId;
  private int bookId;
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorOfBookRepository extends JpaRepository<,AuthorOfBookId> {

}
```

Now how would I represent that query:

```
SELECT b.name, a.firstname, a.lastname from AuthorOfBook ab inner join Book b on b.id = ab.book_id inner join Author a on a.id = ab.author_id where a.lastname = :lastname;
```

in my repository? I know the signature would need to be like

```
@Query([the query string from above])
public (...) findAuthorAndBookByAuthorLastname(@Param("lastname") String lastname);
```

but I cannot make out what Type the return would be like. What is that method returning? (simply `AuthorOfBook` would not work I guess)

Comment: By reading your query it looks like you are looking for term projection or widely known as dto which is covered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401734/how-to-work-with-dto-in-spring-data-rest-projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `AuthorOfBook` as a separate Entity. `Book` should have a field of type `Author` as a @ManyToOne relationship. That way, given any `Book`, you can find the author's details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So even in my Entity-representation I want to wire the entities with relations and not just represent the database-structure? I'd have the following questions on that:   Assuming I have additional information in my relationship-database (like a `created`-timestamp) - would I pick the same structure and let JPA handle that? And how do I handle a third ID in that? So I have `BookId`, `AuthorId` and `CustomerId`?

Comment: And one more thing: That would mean for me, that I never want to have ForeignKeys in my `@Entity`? So everytime I would reference a `Foreign-Key-Constraint` I use a direct reference to that other Entity instead?

Comment: Yes, the relations should be shown in your entities. That is representing your database structure, as typically you would have foreign key constraints in your database, and the joins (@OneToOne, @OneToMany or @ManyToMany) represent those foreign key relationships. A `created` timestamp usually represents the time that the entity (such as `Book`) was created. The relationship between a `Book` and an `Author` would be created at the same time. Customer would be a separate entity again, and would be a @ManyToMany relationship. Please ask a new question if you're unclear on that.

Comment: You might have `ForeignKey`s in your entities. They are used for schema generation.

Comment: Thank you for your effort :) As suggested, I tried to realise it with 3 tables that are connected and opened a new question since I ran into problems (can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733602/how-to-wire-up-three-classes-in-spring-boot-jpa-instead-of-two-with-manytomany). Could you also have a look at that and what I was doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle audits fields you can do something like this:

Audit class

```
@Embeddable
public class Audit {

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Timestamp createdOn;

    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    private Timestamp updatedOn;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    //getters and setters

    }
```

AuditListener to update automatically audits fields

```
public class AuditListener {

    private Long loggedUser = 1001L;

    /**
     * Method to set the fields createdOn, and isDeleted when an entity is persisted
     * @param auditable
     */
    @PrePersist
    public void setCreatedOn(Auditable auditable) {
        Audit audit = auditable.getAudit();

        if (audit == null) {
            audit = new Audit();
            auditable.setAudit(audit);
        }

        audit.setIsDeleted(Boolean.FALSE);
        audit.setCreatedOn(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
    }

    /**
     * Method to set the fields updatedOn and updatedBy when an entity is updated
     * @param auditable
     */
    @PreUpdate
    public void setUpdatedOn(Auditable auditable) {
        Audit audit = auditable.getAudit();
        audit.setUpdatedOn(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
    }
}
```

And add this to the entities

```
@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
public class Book implements Auditable {

    @Embedded
    private Audit audit;
```