# Remove association links for content on collection resource for Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, jackson2

How configure **Spring Data REST** to remove entity association links (left only "self") on Collection resource response of **Repository interface endpoints**, without set *exported=false* on @ResResource annotation (need keep exported the endpoints)

We has entities where the **_links** part has the bigest size on the response:

- On [Item resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource) _ *links* are useful to navigate throught the associations.
- But on [Collection Resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource) , mainly on large collections, this information is not important and makes the response unnecesary biger .

We need change this response:

```
    {
     "_embedded" : {
     "persons" : [ {
       "id" : "bat_3191",
       "name" : "B",
       "_links" : {     // 80% of response size !!
            "self" : {
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/bat_3191"
            },
            "orders" : {
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/bat_3191/order"
            },
            "payments" : {
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/bat_3191/payments"
            },
            "childrens" : {
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/bat_3191/childrens"
            },
            "invoices" : {
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/bat_3191/invoices"
            },
            "brands" : {
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/bat_3191/brands"
            },
        }
      },
      { person [2] } 
        ... 
      { person [N] }
      ]
    },
      "_links" : {
       [page links]
    }
```

To a only "self" on _links part:

```
{
"_embedded" : {
"persons" : [ {
  "id" : "bat_3191",
  "name" : "B",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/bat_3191"
    }
  }
}, {
  "id" : "bat_2340",
  "name" : "B",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/bat_2340"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401734/how-to-work-with-dto-in-spring-data-rest-projects

Comment: Sorry if I dont explain clear my question but is not duplicate for the proposed. We need remove the relations on _link  part of the JSON for all entities to reduce the response size on collection request.  I achived it refactoring the PersistentEntityJackson2Module to avoid that Jackson serielize the Links  but I am sure that will be a better aproach. I dont know how to do with RestRespositoryMvcConfiguration to modified this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to control the hateos links in springboot I used a resource assembler. As an example:

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeAddressResourceAssembler assembler;

@GetMapping(value="/{empId}", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeAddressResource> getEmployeeAddress(@PathVariable Integer empId) {
    EmployeeAddressItem employeeAddressItem = restTemplate.getForObject( 
        serviceUrl + "/employee/address/{empId}", 
        EmployeeAddressItem.class, empId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok( assembler.toResource(employeeAddressItem) );
}
```

And then I used the resource assembler.

```
@Component
public class EmployeeAddressResourceAssembler
        extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<EmployeeAddressItem, EmployeeAddressResource> {

    public EmployeeAddressResourceAssembler() {
        super(EmployeeAddressController.class, EmployeeAddressResource.class);
    }

    @Override
    public EmployeeAddressResource toResource(EmployeeAddressItem item) {

        // createResource(employeeAddressItem);
        EmployeeAddressResource resource = createResourceWithId(item.getEmpId(), item);
        resource.fromEmployeeAddressItem(item);
        // … do further mapping
        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeAddressController.class).deleteEmployeeAddress(item.getEmpId())).withRel("delete"));        
        return resource;
    }

}
```

and the ResourceAssembler uses a Resource

```
public class EmployeeAddressResource extends ResourceSupport {
    private Integer empId;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String address3;
    private String address4;
    private String state;
    private String country;

    public void fromEmployeeAddressItem(EmployeeAddressItem item) {
        this.empId = item.getEmpId();
        this.address1 = item.getAddress1();
        this.address2 = item.getAddress2();
        this.address3 = item.getAddress3();
        this.address4 = item.getAddress4();
        this.state = item.getState();
        this.country = item.getCountry();
    }
```

All this at [RestPracticeWithHateos](https://github.com/karlnicholas/RestPracticeWithHateos)

Comment: This aproach works fine with HATEOAS but we need for Spring Data REST where PersistentEntityResourceAssembler, PersistentEntityResource and RepositoryEntityController are the classes that model the resource-link transformation. How to customize the Resource/links for a Entity on Collection Resources returned by Respositories of Spring data REST and defined projections is the goal.